# Adding items to APp

Tags: 2sxc

Im having problems adding items with Datalist Option, I can see 4 or 5 items there but items are not rendered, just first one.

If I add item from control bar item appears but from itemsgrid, items are not being displayed into app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is extremely generic and hard to answer. Please look at some demo-apps, you probably did not include a loop (which would go through all items) and are only showing one in your template.

Comment: Sorry but i was ignoring the content or data funcionality, is solved now